# How to reference first argument of function from second? (python 2.7)

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, arguments, user-defined-functions

Let's say I have a generic function like this:

```
def do_thing(arg1, default=len(arg1)):
```

assuming arg1 is this string: `"hello, world!"`, the *default* would be `13`.
if arg1 was `"oh yeah"`, default would be `7`.

Just assume that since the default *is* a default, I can change it by doing `do_thing("hello", 1)` for example.

from that point, I get a traceback saying that arg1 is not defined. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like so:

```
def do_thing(arg1, default=None):
  if default is None:
    default = len(arg1)
   ...
```

Or if `None` is a possible valid value, create a new sentinel object:

```
_nolen = object()

def do_thing(arg1, default=_nolen):
  if default is _nolen:
    default = len(arg1)
   ...
```